# How do I select the web.whatsapp.com search bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, webkit

I want to programmatically set focus on the web.whatsapp.com search bar:

[image]

I inspect this element in Chrome 's source code explorer, and I see this:

[image]

I right-click the element, then click "Copy->selector".

It provides: "#side > div.uwk68 > div > div"

So I tried this:

```
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('#side > div.uwk68 > div > div');
```

It returns 0 elements.

How could I select this search bar?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use document.querySelector like

```
var element = document.querySelector("div._13NKt.copyable-text.selectable-text");
```

This is listed along with the other things you can use in this reference for the HTML DOM

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp

Comment: No I'm not sure about it, I don't want to download the app on my phone because it is asking for that. How are you running code on their website?

Comment: I have edited your code according to what Chrome devtools -> element -> copy selector said.